# Is it possible to force case-sensitivity in MATLAB for file operations like LOAD?

Tags: matlab, file-io, case-sensitive

MATLAB is case-sensitive for calling functions, even on Windows:

```
>> edit Untitled
>> untitled
Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'untitled'
```

Is there a way to enforce case sensitivity on Windows for other functions, like load?

```
>> a = 3;
>> save a a
>> load A
```

The problem is that this code will run fine on Windows, but will error if I send it to a friend on Unix.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a Matlab version issue? On OS X 10.8.4 and R2012b `load` seems to be case-insensitive just like you say Windows is. What versions of Matlab and what flavor of UNIX?

Comment: `load` is only case-insensitive in the filename, not the variable name (unless you don't specify the latter). `save file a` with `load file A` returns a warning, but `load FiLe a` does not. You should specify what sort of solution you're looking for. Programmatic? Something in the Matlab/OS preferences?

Comment: @horchler: you may be right about that point (I dont have a Mac/Linux version to confirm), but I think that the OP is asking to enforce case-sensitivity either way

Answer (score 1):

One way to enforce case-sensitivity for functions dealing with files, regardless of the platform you are running, is to write a wrapper for such functions.

For example, in the case of `load`, I came up with the following drop-in replacement:

```
function varargout = myload(fname, varargin)
    % make sure filename ends with MAT extension
    [~,~,ext] = fileparts(fname);
    if isempty(ext), fname = [fname '.mat']; end

    % open file (searching entire MATLAB path)
    fid = fopen(fname,'r');
    if fid < 0, error('file not found'); end

    % get fullpath to opened file, and close file handle
    filename = fopen(fid);
    fclose(fid);

    % extract the filename
    [~,name,ext] = fileparts(filename);
    filename = [name ext];

    % compare against original name (case-sensitive)
    if ~strcmp(fname,filename)
        error('Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for file');
    end

    % load the MAT-file
    S = load(fname, varargin{:});

    % assign output
    if nargout > 0
        varargout{1} = S;
    else
        fn = fieldnames(S);
        for i=1:numel(fn)
            assignin('caller', fn{i}, S.(fn{i}))
        end
    end
end
```

I may have missed a few cases in the above implementation, but you get the idea..

Comment: we could have also used `which` instead of `fopen` to retrieve the actual filename with the correct case